# Webpack dev server Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, webpack-5

The problem is that I get this very error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) when I use webpack-dev-server.
But if I just build the project then I can run my index.html and get the expected result.
My project structure is:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button id="displayNumber">Show/Change Number</button>
        
        
        <span id="number">15</span>
    </div>

    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here're webpack config file

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/js/script.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'dist'
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
            publicPath: '/dist/',
        },
        open: true,
        hot: true,
    }
}
```

So when I run webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js CLI command then I get the error.
And when I run webpack --config webpack.prod.js and then open index.html everything works just fine.
My question is why does webpack-dev-server behaves that oddly? What am I missing?